Looking for the proper solution. 36 V DC DPDT switch?
New to electronics, this may be too simple, but I’m not sure what to do. I am building a motorized beach cart using a 36 V brushed motor, motor controller and throttle, powered by (2) 20 V DeWalt tool batteries.
Two questions.

I am looking to add a switch to reverse polarity. The one I used prior - fried. I can not seem to find a DC switch at 20 - 30 amps.  I’m seeing lots of relays. Is that what I need? I’ve never wired a relay so I’d need some direction.

If I’m running 40 V, how would I add 12 V accessories for example LED strip light?  Do I need to somehow step it down?


That’s a good start, more questions to come. Thanks in advance for looking.


For simple polarity reversal, you need a Double-Pole, Double Throw (DPDT) something - switch or relay. Digi-Key and Newark Electronics have big, fat toggle switches, but they're not cheap.  If you go with a lower power SPST switch and a DPDT relay, the relay wiring is the same as for the switch.  Ask and ye shall receive a schematic.

Yes, you need a voltage regulator rated for greater than 40 V input, a 12 V output, and an output current rating at least 50% greater than your expected total 12 V load current (for margin).  Depending on the output current (which determines how much heat is dissipated in the regulator), this can be either a linear type or switching type (called a buck regulator).  This can be an ebay module.


Voltage regulators come in a wide array of sizes and capabilities.  In general, the regulator's input voltage range must include the output voltage range of whatever is powering it.  The regulator's output current must be able to handle the load that is attached to it.  If you are powering a string of LEDs designed to run directly off of 12 V, then the datasheet for the LEDs should list the current required.
Based on your questions, I'm guessing that you want to wire together devices rather than construct a regulator circuit from scratch.  dbay has a ton of low cost buck regulator modules with terminal block inputs and outputs, so the only tool needed is a small screwdriver; and a waterproof enclosure.
For a more detailed answer, please update you question with more information about the 12 V loads.

I would like a schematic of relay and switch please. I’m confused. If I use a relay, I can use an spst switch? Is there no ( forward /off / reverse ) I guess if the motors not spinning it shouldn’t be an issue. Secondly the voltage regulator, I need the load of what m looking to add? If I don’t know is there something that would work otherwise?

Your question asked about forward/reverse, which can be done with either one DPDT switch, or one DPDT relay controlled by one SPST switch.  Forward/off/reverse is a different problem, and doing that with relays is a bit more complicated than using a DPDT on-off-on switch.  Regulator: see expanded answer.

@Dave in your question you write that you already have a controller and throttle. Surely that provides 'off' and you ain't need the reverse switch to also do so?

Here's a design that could fit your requirements:

simulate this circuit – Schematic created using CircuitLab
This uses relays to control power to the motor (and its polarity), and manual switches to control relay coil current. The contacts of relays RLY1 and RLY2  contact must be rated for the 30A of DC motor current, but switches SW1 and SW2 can be much less beefy, required only to pass relay coil current, which could be, say, only 1A depending on the model of relay.
Relay RLY1 simply cuts/connects power to the motor, and relay RLY2 (a DPDT type) is wired to swap that power's polarity when activated. Don't omit the diodes; they suppress the voltage spikes caused by the relay coils, which would damage SW1 and SW2. Take care with the diodes' polarity, if you get that wrong they will explode.
The DC-DC converter (a "buck" type) provides 12V, which is used for the relay coils, so your relays must have coils rated for 12V DC. This will also permit you to power other peripheral 12V equipment. The converter must be able to withstand over 40V at its input, and its output must be capable of sourcing all current for the relay coils and any peripheral devices. In other words, if your relay coils require 1A each, and all your peripherals require a total of 2A, then the buck converter must be able to provide at least 4A of current.
I hope I don't need to remind you to use heavy gauge wire for all the high-current paths, shown in blue above. It is essential to connect the far ends of motor power wires as close to the battery terminals as possible, at X and Y. The DC-DC converter inputs should have their own separate wires, also connected right at the battery terminals. Do not branch wires off the motor wiring, to power the DC-DC converter, or anything else.
